# Crash when set a property frequently in different thread synchronously

Tags: ios, multithreading

The code like this:

```
for _ in 0...3 {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        for i in 0 ... 30000 {
            self.aString = "\(i)"
        }
    }
}
```

When run this code, it will crash:

> malloc: *** error for object 0x6100000569de: Invalid pointer dequeued
>   from free list

And if I add lock into the thread, it works fine, like a serial queue:

```
for _ in 0...3 {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        self.lock.lock() // NSRecursiveLock
        for i in 0 ... 30000 {
            self.aString = "\(i)"
        }
        self.lock.unlock()
    } 
}
```

In my opinion, modify same data in different thread may cause the incorrect data, but why crashed ?

Comment: Can you share more details about your class? Is aString just a regular? Are you doing anything when setting aString?

Comment: @HAK Just a property of a ViewController, and call the code when click a button.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using global queue use main queue and it won't crash.

```
for _ in 0...3 {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        for i in 0 ... 30000 {
            self.aString = "\(i)"
        }
    }
}
```

Don't know exactly why it is happening in the first place but using the main queue will solve it.

Comment: Yup, I think this because the async main thread is serial. So there will be no situation where the property is modified at the same time and it won't crash. While the global is concurrent. I just want to know why crash.

Comment: I read somewhere, setting a property multiple times very quickly can cause this error as well. Change the count from 30000 to 20 and it won't crash on the global queue as well. But increase it to 30 and it will start crashing again.